# Win32 uses macros with parameters for this, which breaks C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, macros

I have a problem with afxv_32.h. VS 2012 cannot find AFX_INLINE and HTASK. It is specified that "Win32 uses macros with parameters for this, which breaks C++ code". Apparently AFX_INLINE is a macro. I've been looking for it for a long time and I didn't find it. Do you have any idea how to deal with this ?

```
    // Win32 uses macros with parameters for this, which breaks C++ code.
    #ifdef GetWindowTask
    #undef GetWindowTask
    AFX_INLINE HTASK GetWindowTask(HWND hWnd)
        { return (HTASK)(DWORD_PTR)::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL); }
    #endif

    // Win32 uses macros with parameters for this, which breaks C++ code.
    #ifdef GetNextWindow
    #undef GetNextWindow
    AFX_INLINE HWND GetNextWindow(HWND hWnd, UINT nDirection)
        { return ::GetWindow(hWnd, nDirection); }
    #endif

    // Avoid mapping CToolBar::DrawState to DrawState[A/W]
    #ifdef DrawState
    #undef DrawState
    AFX_INLINE BOOL WINAPI DrawState(HDC hdc, HBRUSH hbr, DRAWSTATEPROC lpOutputFunc,
        LPARAM lData, WPARAM wData, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, UINT fuFlags)
    #ifdef UNICODE
        { return ::DrawStateW(hdc, hbr, lpOutputFunc, lData, wData, x, y, cx, cy,
            fuFlags); }
    #else
        { return ::DrawStateA(hdc, hbr, lpOutputFunc, lData, wData, x, y, cx, cy,
            fuFlags); }
    #endif
    #endif

    // Avoid mapping CStatusBar::DrawStatusText to DrawStatusText[A/W]
    #ifdef DrawStatusText
    #undef DrawStatusText
    AFX_INLINE void WINAPI AfxDrawStatusTextA(HDC hDC, LPRECT lprc, LPCTSTR szText,
        UINT uFlags);
    AFX_INLINE void WINAPI AfxDrawStatusTextW(HDC hDC, LPRECT lprc, LPCTSTR szText,
        UINT uFlags);
    AFX_INLINE void WINAPI DrawStatusText(HDC hDC, LPRECT lprc, LPCTSTR szText,
        UINT uFlags) 
    #ifdef UNICODE
        { ::AfxDrawStatusTextW(hDC, lprc, szText, uFlags); }
    #else
        { ::AfxDrawStatusTextA(hDC, lprc, szText, uFlags); }
    #endif
    #endif

    // FreeResource is not required on Win32 platforms
    #undef FreeResource
    AFX_INLINE BOOL WINAPI FreeResource(_In_ HGLOBAL) { return TRUE; }
    // UnlockResource is not required on Win32 platforms
    #undef UnlockResource
    AFX_INLINE int WINAPI UnlockResource(HGLOBAL) { return 0; }
```

Comment: There is no question here. It seems the header is solving a problem you think it is creating. I doubt an MFC (which is a C++ library) breaks when compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: AFX_INLINE is an MFC macro that likely just means `inline`.

Comment: Yes I know this is strange. But that's ok, the error has disappeared. I have just included windef.h. OK I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

You will find those macros in `afxisapi.h`.

Comment: Yes thanks. This is what I did first but it didn't work, because I didn't have this file on my computer. So I created it and included it but didn't work neither

Comment: It is now included in a separate package AFAIK. I don't know where you can find it though.

Comment: OK thanks, i'm gonna try to find it. For the moment I do not have this error ;)